# iOS 14 limited photo library access state change

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, mobile

Can I handle limited access (iOS 14 new feature) state change of photo library? For example, user changed set of photoes, accessed by the app, and is there any event to handle the change of it?

Tried to use `AppState` change event and `react-native-navigator` focused state change – both didn't worked.

Natively or using React Native.
Thanks, have a nice day!